# How to get OrganizationId after Login -Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-theme

I am using liferay6.I  deployed my web application inside liferay.After Login,it is redirecting to one page.In that jsp page,i want to set organization id of logged in user in a javascript variable.How can i do this.Can anyone pls explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can get `userId` of logged in User by `themeDisplay.getUserId()`
2. Using this `userId`, you can get the User's Organizations by `OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getUserOrganizations(userId)`
3. Then you can iterate through the Organizations to get the organizationId you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
 com.liferay.portal.model.Group currentGroup;
    long organizationId = 0;
    try {
        currentGroup = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroup();
        if (currentGroup.isOrganization()) {
            organizationId = currentGroup.getClassPK();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

    return organizationId;
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Code-only answers are best avoided because they don't help others as much as well-explained, commented answers.